# gDebugger libGL error on linux

Tags: linux, opengl

I'm trying to debug my OpenGl project with gDEBugger, but unfortunately gDEBugger is not even starting:

```
~/bin/gDEBugger581-x86_64> ./gDEBugger-bin 
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
Segmentation fault
~/bin/gDEBugger581-x86_64> LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose ./gDEBugger-bin 
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/updates/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/updates/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib64/dri/updates/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib64/dri/updates    /swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so:     undefined symbol: _glapi_tls_Dispatch)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Segmentation fault
```

this happens with the last gremedy version (5.8.1), the last AMD version (6.2.4) and the latest CodeXL version (CodeXL doesn't crash, but the same error appears non the less and debugging doesn't work).

I'm on OpenSuse 13.1, I have a NVIDIA card and the latest drivers installed. Other OpenGL programms work just fine. So far I've tried to reinstall NVIDIA drivers, reinstall all MESA packages, update CUDA from 5.5 to 6.5, checked that all mesa packages are installed from the standard suse repo and ran ldd:

```
~/bin/gDEBugger581-x86_64> ldd gDEBugger-bin 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe9ffe000)
    libGRBaseTools.so => ./libGRBaseTools.so (0x00007f41df93e000)
    libGROSWrappers.so => ./libGROSWrappers.so (0x00007f41df6cc000)
    libGRAPIClasses.so => ./libGRAPIClasses.so (0x00007f41df358000)
    libGRProcessDebugger.so => ./libGRProcessDebugger.so (0x00007f41df123000)
    libGRApiFunctions.so => ./libGRApiFunctions.so (0x00007f41deedf000)
    libGRApplicationComponents.so => ./libGRApplicationComponents.so (0x00007f41debce000)
    libgDEBuggerAppCode.so => ./libgDEBuggerAppCode.so (0x00007f41de5b0000)
    libwx_base-2.8.so.0 => ./libwx_base-2.8.so.0 (0x00007f41de29e000)
    libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so.0 => ./libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so.0 (0x00007f41ddcd9000)
    libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so.0 => ./libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so.0 (0x00007f41dda2f000)
    libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so.0 => ./libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so.0 (0x00007f41dd753000)
    libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so.0 => ./libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so.0 (0x00007f41dd4e2000)
    libwx_gtk2_gl-2.8.so.0 => ./libwx_gtk2_gl-2.8.so.0 (0x00007f41dd2d5000)
    libwx_gtk2_stc-2.8.so.0 => ./libwx_gtk2_stc-2.8.so.0 (0x00007f41dcfcb000)
    libfreeimage.so.3 => ./libfreeimage.so.3 (0x00007f41dcc35000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f41dc92d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f41dc62a000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f41dc413000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f41dc065000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f41dbe61000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f41dbc59000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f41dba3b000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f41db6fd000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f41db4e7000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f41db19b000)
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f41dab5c000)
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f41da8a7000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f41da683000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f41da31c000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f41da108000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f41d9ee7000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f41d9c9b000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f41d9a09000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f41d97cc000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f41d957b000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f41d9377000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f41d9175000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f41d8e72000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f41d8c6f000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f41d8a69000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f41d8861000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f41d85e2000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f41dfb49000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f41d83c3000)
    libnvidia-tls.so.340.32 => /usr/lib64/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.340.32 (0x00007f41d81c0000)
    libnvidia-glcore.so.340.32 => /usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.32 (0x00007f41d55ad000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f41d539b000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f41d518e000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f41d4f88000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f41d4c69000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f41d4a5f000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f41d484f000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f41d4645000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f41d443a000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f41d4237000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f41d4034000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f41d3e10000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f41d3bf9000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f41d39a6000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib64/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f41d3769000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f41d353f000)
    libffi.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libffi.so.4 (0x00007f41d3337000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f41d30d1000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f41d2eb5000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f41d2cb0000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f41d2aac000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f41d2803000)
    libEGL.so.1 => /usr/X11R6/lib64/libEGL.so.1 (0x00007f41d24fa000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f41d22f7000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f41d20ed000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f41d1ed1000)
    libnvidia-glsi.so.340.32 => /usr/lib64/libnvidia-glsi.so.340.32 (0x00007f41d1c49000)
```

I noticed, that when running my own program with `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose` there is not libGL output at all. I'm using glfw 2.7 and glew 1.9 if it matters. glut apps work.

I suppose that gDEBugger has a different way to find and load libGL and somehow it ends up using the mesa one and not the nvidia one. but my knowledge of mesa and nvidia driver and the workings of it are quite limited.

edit:
new information:

```
strace -e open ./gDEBugger-bin 2>&1 | grep libGL.so
open("./tls/x86_64/libGL.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./tls/libGL.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./x86_64/libGL.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./libGL.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/lib64/libGL.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/damdam/bin/pgmodeler/libGL.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so.340.32", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so.340.32", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so.340.32", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
open("/usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so.340.32", O_RDONLY) = 7
open("/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 7
```

for comparison, this is the same for a working program: http://paste.opensuse.org/76645738
and this is the full output (without grep): http://paste.opensuse.org/8336779

i tried to setup the following links in `/usr/lib64/`:

```
 libGLESv1_CM.so -> /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGLES
 libGLESv1_CM.so.1 -> /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL
 libGLESv1_CM.so.1.1.0 -> /usr/X11R6/lib64/l
 libGLESv2.so -> /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGLESv2.
 libGLESv2.so.2 -> /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGLESv
 libGLESv2.so.2.0.0 -> /usr/X11R6/lib64/libG
 libGL.so -> /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so
 libGL.so.1 -> /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so
 libGL.so.1.2 -> /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so
 libGL.so.1.2.0 -> /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so
```

after that the behaviour changed, the program crashed with a segfault and not printing anything.

edit:
new information
the gremedy gDEBugger (5.8.1) doesn't load /usr/lib64/libGL.so any more when

```
 export LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH="/usr/X11R6/lib64/"
```

it just crashes. so my guess is now, that it knew about the correct libGL all the time, but couldn't load it. either there is something strange with my system, or i'm the first reporting about this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with the same distro, same release. Eventually I traced it to the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I had added `/usr/lib/` and `/usr/lib64/` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to try to resolve a linking problem.  It seems including those directories in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` meant `/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1` from the package Mesa-libGL1 hid `/usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so.1` from the package `x11-video-nvidiaG02`.

Re-exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` without those two directories had libGL sorted out and working again.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages indicate that for some reason gDEBugger dynamically links a Mesa variant of `libGL.so` (only Mesa tries to talk the DRI protocol). With your NVidia GPU in the system and I presume the NVidia proprietary drivers being installed and configured as well, this indicates, something is seriously off.

The other possibility is, that you're don't have the NVidia proprietary drivers installed at all and are running completely off Mesa. The problem is, that the NVidia GPU support of Mesa is only rudimentary for any GPU built past 2005.

Note that if you're using the NVidia proprietary drivers you don't need Mesa being installed at all (although having it and using the Mesa libGL.so as linking target for your programs, even if the NVidia libGL.so is used at runtime is quite sensible).

Comment: i was thinking of something like that, but i have no idea how to find and fix the problem.

yes, nvidia drivers are installed. as said, other opengl programs run fine.

would you suggest to try de-installing mesa?

Comment: @Adam: In case of doubt: Stop the X11 server, log into a text console, uninstall all packages related to implementing OpenGL (mesa, nvidia drivers, and such), `find / -name 'libGL.so' -print -delete` and reinstall the NVidia drivers.

Comment: @Adam: To analyze the problem compare the output of `ldd $(which glxinfo)` with that of `ldd gDEBugger-bin` regarding libGL.so. Then check of the file they link against belongs to NVidia or Mesa (may be a symbolic link so you have to follow that to the end).

Comment: i just tried to de-install mesa but a ton of packages depends on it. the only thing i was able to de-install, was DirectFB-Mesa, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: this is the output of ldd for glxinfo: http://paste.opensuse.org/29029986, looks to me the same. my own programs also pointed to the same location in /usr/X11R6/lib64/.

i tried to find libGL.so files: http://paste.opensuse.org/97456860
the ones in X11R6 seem to be nvidia:
    `ll /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so
    /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1
    /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.340.32`

for the one in `/usr/lib64/ i made a link to the nvidia one. nothing changed.

Comment: @Adam what does `strace -e open ./gDEBugger-bin 2>&1 | grep libGL.so` say?

Comment: i updated the information in the question. as far as i understand it, it opens the wrong libGL, but it sees the correct one. i have no idea why and how to fix..

Comment: I updated the question once more. Right now I don't think it's solvable anymore. Not without reinstalling Linux and testing with a different distribution, maybe with different nvidia driver versions.